# Rails still caches views/controllers even when caching disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I enabled the development env, and disabled caching. Yet it still continues to cache. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am running Rails using Ubuntu on WSL2.

Comment: Have you restart the server after disabling caching?

Comment: The service needs to be restarted after the configuration file is modified.

Comment: I have restarted it.